# Неверная дата через функцию Date()

Tags: php

Выводится через локальный вебсервер (Open Server)

Почему выводит неверную дату?

```
Date('Y-m-d', 1666126800) // 2022-10-19
```

Должен быть результат `2022-10-18`

Делал проверку в онлайн сервисе https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/xDe `2022-10-18`

Ниже код на локальном

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В документации https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php   написано почему и что делать. В частности там написано Метки времени Unix не обрабатывают часовые пояса. Используйте класс DateTimeImmutable и его метод форматирования DateTimeInterface::format() для форматирования информации о дате/времени с привязкой к часовому поясу.

Comment: или использовать `date_default_timezone_set('XXXXX');`  для выставления часового пояса по умолчанию (это тоже пример из документации)